# Convert string type to Instance type

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, intervals

I have a dict(image attached below):
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3SYv.png

The keys of the dict is a dataframe. When trying to upload this dict to json I had to convert `column a` to string type from interval type. But when I want to use the json I want to convert the values of `column a` back to interval type.
Below are the things I've tried:

```
k = dict.keys()
for keys in k:
   dict[keys]["a"] = dict[keys]["a"].astype("interval")
```

But it throws the below error:
`TypeError: type <class 'str'> with value (-inf, -9999999.0] is not an interval`

Can you please help me with the way to convert `column a` values from string to Interval types?

Comment: I think this question has been answered already but without inf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295837/turn-string-representation-of-interval-into-actual-interval-in-pandas

inf can be converted with np.array([np.inf]).astype(int)[0] or math.inf (or -math.inf for negative infinity)

Answer (score -1):

(See  [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings))

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> eval("Foo")
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Comment: You are only looking at the question title, and not the question details. They are not asking for *arbitrary* conversions.